# Can I find correlation with words in Python?

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn

Can I find another method in python like `findassocs()` in R?

I am trying to find association with words in python. However, I can't find any package has that method.

```py
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df = 5)
    count = vectorizer.fit_transform(token_doc) 
    print(count)
    print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
    tftrans = TfidfTransformer()
    tfidf = tftrans.fit_transform(count).toarray()
    print(tfidf)
    print(tftrans.vocabulary_)
```

How can I get a correlation word with word-list is based on Tf-Idf?

If the process that I mentioned is done, I want to put a word in a method and let method me know which word is the most associated word.

you can check what the `findassocs` is.

It can take input word and return word list that shows which word is associated with.